# How to validate emails with error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

[Update] I still dont know what to put in my else of my create conroller to put and error message.
I am trying to validate the format of users email.

This is the html the error is coming from

```
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article 
from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I experimented with this from an old ruby video but it didn't seen to pan out.

This is my `user.rb` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validates :email, format: { with: /(\A([a-z]*\s*)*\<*([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\>*\Z)/i }
end
```

I get these errors currently

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil},
>   missing required keys: [:id]

and

> undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

whenever the password or email makes an error from the requirements.

my create action in my sessions controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @user = User.new 
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: can you paste a link of URL you're accessing?

Comment: the video? @RishiPithadiya

Comment: I think posting the view/form that's throwing the error would be helpful

Comment: if you are not using devise, can you pleas post your view form & create action from the controller ?, because i think in create action your @user object is some how vanished so you need to re-initiate or add **render :new** if issue in email or password.

Comment: I'd imagine it's the line where he creates the form that contains the error

Comment: Add the whole stack trace of the error.

Comment: The error you are encountering has nothing to do with the code you posted nor with the title of your question. As Sebastian says, show the whole stack trace and *relevant* code.

Comment: Is `@user` defined at the controller? also you have `@user` and `@users` (plural).

Comment: i added my full trace and the first part of code is the html that the error brings also, the create action in my session controller

Comment: Why haven't you shown the full create action? Please add it. Infact please include the whole controllerl

Comment: It would also be useful to see the full stack trace including the very beginning. You can get it from your log file

Comment: I have included my full create action but i will edit it and show my whole controller

Comment: Please stop constantly editing the code in your question. There is no way there can be a valid answer for your question if it changes all the time. If an answer was useful, please accept it. If you have further questions based on some new understanding, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no user with the requested `email` address, your `@user` variable will be `nil` in the controller (since this is the returned value of the `find_by_email` method if nothing is found)

In that case, you are explicitly rendering your `new` view which then attempts to render errors on the `@user` object. However, since the variable is `nil` instead of the `User` object you are apparently expecting there, `nil.errors` fails with the error you are seeing there.

To solve this, you should either check in your view if you have an actual `@user` object, or render a more suitable view from your controller.

Comment: i tried puts user instance variable in the view and nothing showed up what does that necessarily mean @Holger Just

Answer (score 1):

3 issues here

```
  def create
    @user = User.create(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
```

That function tries to create a user and regardless of success it then goes on to redirect to the show action

1) You need to check if the User.create actually succeeds then take appropriate action

2) You have no route for the show action so you need to fix that but

3) None of your actions are specifying the format. What happens if someone is using an XML feed Are you sure you want to show the user, Just show a list of users, there won't be anything much to see

Several people including asked for the full stack trace which you seem to have ignored. This would be so much easier to track down the origination of your error had you done so, including the params sent to the create action

```
  def create
    if @user = User.create(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
```

Now you have to track down why the create failed
You should also show the errors to the user by using a flash message

Comment: my full stack trace is to long to insert into my question and i have changed my conroller to check if user#create is working  def create
    user = User.create(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])
    if user.save
        redirect_to user_path(user)
    else
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
     end

Comment: @codeprodigy Full stack trace would not be too long. When people ask for more information it's not for fun. You need to help people to help you. So now you have udated your create action I assume everything is OK? Of course until you set your route for the show action you will eventually stumble on the no route matches error. If not OK then update your question

Comment: it is giving me and error and my mac feels like its about to crash when i paste my stack trace. But now that i fixed my controller and don't have and error I don't think its necessary for the rest of my question

Comment: @codeprodigy Cool, feel free to accept my answer. Glad to help